# What exactly does a minor vertex on a hyperbola represent?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The equation for a hyperbola involves $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is its major vertex length and $b$ is its minor vertex length. I understand that the major vertex represents the intersection point of its major axis and the hyperbola, but what exactly does the minor vertex represent? I have seen several diagrams that show a hyperbola with its major and minor vertices, but none of them necessarily explain *what* the minor vertex represents. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a diagram with a "major vertex" or "minor vertex" labeled on it. I've only seen one "vertex" on each branch of the hyperbola, which makes two vertices altogether. It also seems to be difficult to find a diagram on which any kind of "vertex length" is marked; but the variables $a$ and $b$ are often used to represent half the lengths of the transverse and conjugate axes. It would be interesting if you could provide a link to one of your diagrams or at least describe where you found it.

Answer (score 1):

For either hyperbola $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=\pm 1,$
if one completes a rectangle, sides parallel to axes, passing through $(\pm a.0),(0,\pm b)$ as side midpoints and centered at $(0,0),$ then the extended diagonals of that rectangle are the asymptotes.

Answer (score 1):

You may see the meaning of $a$ and $b$ from the picture. The dot-and-dash line is an asymptote:

[image]